# Python: Is line by line execution possible

Tags: python

Is it possible to run code line by line with Python. 
Including running any module code, when used, line by line as well.

I would like to go out and run some code line by line and watch as each of the lines goes through the processing phase and see just what code is getting executed when certain actions occur.  I'm curious how certain values are getting passed off to the interpreter.

Comment: You need to have a look at the [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module.

Comment: You can do this with pretty much any IDE that supports Python, and to me it's more pleasant than using pdb directly. I use Eclipse with the PyDev extension, and I know a lot of people who like PyCharm. You might check those out.

Comment: From just trying <code>pdb</code> it totally processed but showed nothing for the class I was really hoping to see the results of.  Does the regular shell give you the capability or is it not 'complex' enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `python -m pdb mycode.py`, which will run your code in the python debugger (pdb module).

In the debugger you can execute arbitrary code, watch variables, and jump to different places in the code. Specifically, `n` will execute the next line and `h` will show you the debugger help.

Comment: Okay, but how do you break into a class and watch the program flow through a class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want to run just a specific portion of your code, you can jump there (`j`). If you want to run up to some point then you can set a breakpoint (`b`). I suggest you explore the debugger a little (or read a tutorial), it is simple to use and quite powerful.

Comment: In the case of the program I'm trying to run through, a tkinter program. It goes through the imports and comes down to the [code]class GUI:[/code] and then it jumps down to the bottom where [code]root = tk.Tk()[/code] followed by [code]GUI(root).pack(fill = "both", expand = True)[/code] is located.  It doesn't go through any of the other code.  If I try to jump to the [code]def __init__(self, master):[/code] the next line it executes after that goes back to GUI(root), every line bounces right back to GUI(root) and executes the rest of the code without showing the execution process.

Comment: Also I would like to be able to watch inside the tkinter module as it processes through the module.

Comment: Got it now, stepping through rules.

Answer (score 1):

To add a breakpoint you can use pdb inline:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

From this line bleow you can go step by step and you can enter inside every called function (with s) or jump function execution (with n).
Also, a good tip is to use ipdb instead of pdb because it knows autocomplete (it's an ipython prompt)